# Version of WordNet with reduced polysemy?

Tags: polysemy

WordNet fails to distinguish homographs from polysemes; for my use (related to machine translation), I want to collapse polysemes while maintaining homographs. This idea is not new (eg., [Reducing Polysemy in WordNet](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-551/om2009_poster12.pdf) PDF).

Is there any publicly available WordNet resource where this has already been done?

Comment: Since you already know who worked on this, why not send them an email and ask for their data?

Comment: I did, but haven't heard back yet ... thought I'd ask here, too.